# required initialiser setup to set a property always

Tags: swift, uiview, initialization, swift5

I have this custom view. This view always needs to be instantiated with an Annotation.

```
class MapImageLocationPin: UIView {
    //MARK: - Properties
    private var annotation: Annotation!
    
    //MARK: - Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required convenience init(with annotation: Annotation) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.annotation = annotation
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //MARK: - Configure view
    private func configure() {
        print("Pin initialised! \(annotation.title)")
    }
}
```

The above setup fails (crash, nil value), because configure() is called in self.init, before the annotation is set.

How to solve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
required convenience init(with annotation: Annotation) {
   self.init(frame: .zero)
   self.annotation = annotation
   self.configure()
}
```

You can move configure function after self.annotation assignment

Comment: Thanks! So simple :) I always get confused by initialisers!
How do I make it so annotation is non optional after setting it?

Comment: your welcome! you can mark this answer as resolved if it is ok for you!

Comment: didn't understand you

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer, you can replace your `override init(frame: CGRect)` and your `required convenience init(with annotation: Annotation)` with just one initializer:

```
init(frame: CGRect = .zero, with annotation: Annotation) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.annotation = annotation
    configure()
}
```